# Need to get large chunk of data from service to component in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, angular2-services

I need to pass a very large object to my component from service. Since the object is very large i am intending to divide the object into chunks. 
How can i send the service 'getData()' request at intervals to get the data chunk by chunk?
Basically i don't want the data to come from service at once, but in chunks.
For instance if data is like this - {'x':'1','y':2,'z':3}, then data to to come for x first, then y and so on.
Thanks in advance for any heads up.

Comment: Have you tried to use pagination from server side ? So server will send you data based on you need and call page.

Comment: I have a requirement to not use pagination actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case RxJs [partition](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html) operator might help. Assuming 'large object' is nested object with keys you can implement some logic to return in a sequence you want.

```
const obj = {fist: {name: 'joe', age: 30}, second: {name: 'doe', age: 40}};
//Turn it into iterable
const array = Object.entries(obj);
// make an observable
const source = from(array);
// Logic for how to split, depends on your obj structure
const [under, over] = source.pipe(partition(val => val[1].age < 40));
// result
under.subscribe(a => console.log("Under 30: " + a));
over.subscribe(a => console.log("Over 30: " + a));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** 
 when you got data then dump in local-storage or in cookie then read when you need.

**Option 2:**
If you have so much large data then do some RND for indexDB with angular. It will help you. :) –

[npm i indexeddb-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/indexeddb-angular)